# how to change windows media player hotkeys

Tags: hotkeys, windows-media-player

is there anyway to change windows media player 12 hotkeys? there was a "wmpk" plugin for previous version which right now doesn't work. and my searches didn't lead me anywhere.
of course any other solutions rather than plugins is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Media Player Plus!](https://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmpplus/) plug-in allows you to define global (system-wide) hotkeys for WMP.

Comment: thanx alot. is there any nonglobal hotkey definer? btw way in this community I can't vote up rn but I will vote you up later.

Comment: Not that I know of. The only local hotkey that Windows Media Player Plus! can define is the space bar for starting/pausing playback.